# Баланс на счёте или баланс счёта?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить: баланс на счёте или баланс счёта?

Answer (score 2):

Баланс( **чего?** )счёта.   Денежные **средства на счёте**.

http://big_economic_dictionary.academic.ru/1682/%D0%91%